# XMLHttpRequest.send() sends multiple requests to WebAPI

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

XMLHttpRequest.send() is called only one time, but it sends to WebAPI multiple requests, when WebAPI returns Exception (408).

So [in F12 -> Network I see only one request, but in fiddler multiple ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlpT8.png)
Please, can you explain me, why does it create multiple requests ?

[Click here to see, how I call XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1a0E.png)

Comment: Not an easy question to answer without seeing any source code... my guess is that you don't clear the console after page refresh, so you're seeing all the failed requests, but there could be a number of issues.

Comment: How close together, chronologically, are those multiple requests?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added link to picture, where I show how I call XMLHttpRequest.send().

Comment: can Browser resend request, if it gets 408 errer ?